# Getting : Remove this Redundant Jump in SonarQube

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube, return, void

I have a method in which there is a if else conditions . The if-else looks something similar as below.

```
public void agreementCoduct(String agreement) {
       if(agreement.equals("Pass")) {
         { //do someting
           return; // getting Remove this Redundant Jump
         } else if(aggrement.equals("NotPass")) {
           // do something
           return; // getting Remove this Redundant Jump
        } else {
          // do something 
          return; // getting Remove this Redundant Jump
        }

}
```

I'm running Sonarqube to check the code quality. It is showing the message "Remove this redundant jump." . I want to know how can I remove this Code smell and still achieve what I want. as this is void method so return; should work fine?

Comment: you're using `if if-else else` so you can remove them safely, as once you're in a block you will not enter another one

Comment: Side note `agreement == "Pass"` will probably not work,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return statements have no effect because you do not have any code after the if-elseif-else block. If you remove the return statements, your code will leave the matching if-block and return at the end of the method.

Only the first one of the if-elseif-else blocks that evaluates to true gets executed.

A void-method has an implicit "return" statement in the end.

Answer (score 1):

It's redundant because after the last else you are not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

These `return` statements are redundant, as you are using `if-else if-else` construct. Which means that the code in any one of these blocks will only execute and others will never get executed, which is what you want.